# Why does this two folds return different result just because one has a missing initial value?

Tags: python, functional-programming

I am trying to find the length of the list.

```
In [77]: reduce(lambda acc, x: acc + 1, [x for x in range(8)])
Out[77]: 7

In [78]: reduce(lambda acc, x: acc + 1, [x for x in range(8)], 0)
Out[78]: 8
```

But it seems that I need to pass the initial value for it to work. Why ?

Comment: Is there a reason you're playing around with this instead of just using `len`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't pass a start value, the first value of the list is used as a start value, and never passed as `x` argument to your lambda function, so you actually get `my_list[0] + len(my_list) - 1` as your result.

Comment: I have confirmed that this behaves the same in Haskell.

Answer (score 2):

The first one starts with the first element (0), and adds 1 for the other seven elements. The second starts with 0 and adds 1 for each of the eight elements.